# How can I find a robot's distance from an object given FOV, bounding box measure, and image width and height in pixels?

Tags: kinematics

The robot is standing in the middle of the arena. I am confused on how to convert the pixels into a real life distance and how to use the bounding box. Starting help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey @bobby Welcome to StackExchange Robotics :)
It would be easier for someone to help you if you could add any attempts you made.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* bobby kennedy.  Please edit your question to include more details of your setup, what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to help our members answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The best (and cheapest) method would be to use [AprilTags](https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag). I have added the python bindings for it [here](https://github.com/duckietown/lib-dt-apriltags).

For a great starting point, refer to [this blog](https://www.orangenarwhals.com/2018/04/getting-started-with-apriltags-on-ubuntu-16-04/) that explains the setup in C++.

It can not only tell you the distance but also [the orientation of the object](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/ijae/2019/7050915.pdf)

I hope it helps.